# asp.net mvc routing different actions on the same controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, routes

I have a controller named `Raportare` that has two actions: `ReportA` and `ReportB`.
Both return an excel file based on the parameters supplied.

```
public ActionResult ReportA(int? month, int? year)
{
...
}
public ActionResult ReportB(int? month, int? year)
{
...
}
```

My global.asax has the following routing rules for this :

```
routes.MapRoute(
                "ReportA",
                "{Raportare}/{ReportA}/{month}/{year}",
                new { controller = "Raportare", action = "ReportA", month = UrlParameter.Optional, year = UrlParameter.Optional});

 routes.MapRoute(
                "ReportB",
                "{Raportare}/{ReportB}/{month}/{year}",
                new { controller = "Raportare", action = "ReportB", month = UrlParameter.Optional, year = UrlParameter.Optional });
```

However when I go mysite.com/Raportare/ReportB/5/2012 it's returning the ReportA file.
It works fine if I go to mysite.com/Raportare/ReportB?month=5&year=2012.
Probably I'm doing something wrong in the routing rules but I can't figure it out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to add a route for every action - they work like templates and the 3rd parameter is just default values.

```
routes.MapRoute(
  "reports",
  "Raportare/{action}/{month}/{year}",
  new {
    controller = "Raportare",
    action = "ReportA",
    month = UrlParameter.Optional,
    year = UrlParameter.Optional
  }
);
```

Put this before your default rule in Global.asax.cs, otherwise the default might match first.

Then `mysite.com/Raportare/ReportB/5/2012` will invoke the `ReportB` action because it has been specified in the url.

`mysite.com/Raportare` will invoke `ReportA`, because it is the default action.

Answer (score 0):

The routes you've created are basically the same. That's why the first one which matches request string succeeds and first action gets invoked.